# How do I make Controller and ApiController controllers work in the same project if I remove the api/ level for ApiController controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In a dotnet (not core, 4.7.2) webapi project, I have removed the api/ level in WebApiConfig.Register() because I did not want to have this extra level in the URL paths.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    //routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I need to add one MVC (5) controller (not a Web API controller), let's say Utilities.

Now, when I try to use this controller (https://localhost:44392/Utilities), I get this error:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44392/Utilities'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Utilities'."
}
```

I've spent several hours trying to "play" with routes, but I did not find a way to make ApiController and Controller controllers classes work "together".
If I put back the api/ level, everything works of course, but I would prefer not to have this extra level in the URLs.

Is this at least possible?

Comment: Does your Application_Start() have all required dependencies bootstrapped? Can you show how it looks?

Comment: routeTemplate should be `{controller}/{action}/{id}` Action is not mentioned.

Comment: hello Sh.Imran. Thanks, the idea was good, but now I need to add /get or /post at the end of the url; e.g.: https://localhost:44392/values/get, https://localhost:44392/values/post. I can define a default action (defaults: new { action="get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }), but it does not solve the general problem (got to add the action name in the url for POST, PUT and so on). May be I'm missing something. Thank you.